# iOS drawing to screen

Tags: ios, core-graphics, draw, paint

I am working on drawing to the iOS screen using core graphics, and I managed to be able to draw on the screen, but from the tutorial I followed, the drawing screen covers everything else in my nib file. Can anyone help me figure out how to confine the drawing area to within the view I created in my nib? I've been stuck on this for a while.

The tutorial I followed was this:
http://www.ifans.com/goto/http://www.touchrepo.com/SampleCode/TEST_DRAW_APP.zip

My code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    //Set text from previous
    text.text = [[GameManager sharedManager] inText];

    drawImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];
    drawImage.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self.view addSubview:drawImage];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    mouseSwiped = NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
        drawImage.image = nil;
        return;
    }

    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    lastPoint.y -= 20;

}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    mouseSwiped = YES;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    currentPoint.y -= 20;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;    
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) 
    {
            drawImage.image = nil;
            return;
    }

    if(!mouseSwiped) 
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with extending a UIView in a sub class that I reference from my xib in interface builder. That way I can see the view in interface builder, move it and change it's properties from interface builder. I do it as follows but but you can do this in any order you like:

1. Create a new UIView class instance for your view that you will later link in interface builder.
2. In your new view class override the drawRect method and do your drawing there. Remember to get a reference to the graphics context so that you can draw with it. I see you use the UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() method often. It's better to assign this to a variable to avoid overhead and improve drawing performance if you're doing complex things.
3. In Interface Builder select the view controller you want to put your view in and drag a new view onto your view controller from the Object Library. Resize the blank box as required.
4. Lastly select your view in interface builder and go the the 'Identity Inspector' tab. Choose the class you created earlier under the Custom Class -> Class drop down (if you can't find it here don't worry, restart Xcode and start try again, this happens sometimes).
5. While your view will look blank in interface builder it should draw when you run it in the frame you set for the view.

I see you're drawing when the user touches with the view controller. These touch events can still be handled in your main view controller class. To handle this you can change some properties in your subview and call 'setNeedsDisplay' on your sub view to ensure the sub view's draw method is called on the next display refresh.